# Set a breakpoint to cover all return statements of a method in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, return, breakpoints

I have a quite huge `equals` method in java with a bunch of `return false` statements and one `return true` at the end.

I want to see exactly where the method was exited to know which field was not equal. Is there a way to simple add a breakpoint on method exit regardless of where the method is acutally exited?

I know I could add breakpoints to each return statement but I hope there is an easier way.

Comment: Interesting idea. The first thought of course is: when your method has so many exit point this matters then something is fishy, but hey, who here hasn't used the IDE to generate equals() methods and to then think "wtf"?!

Comment: You could temporarily place the code of equals in its own private method. And in the equals put one breakpoint. In the stack you can then see what return was done. - Or take the opportunity to reduce the number of returns.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's fishy to have many "return false" here. Why evaluate the rest if it's already clear that it's not equal. Sounds like a proper solution to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to place a breakpoint on the line where you declare the method.

e.g `public boolean test() {`

The debugger should brake 2 times. When the method is called and when the method finishes on one of the return statements. This should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like you can even decide if you want to stop at method entry or exit.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to kamentk's answer (thanks for that!) I've seen that there is even an option at method breakpoints to only stop at method entry or exit:

[image]